# removeItemAtPath - error: couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it

Tags: ios, macos, file, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

My code:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
```

My log error:

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x618000255900 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"})
“SecureDelete Lite” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it
```

I have read two topics but they don't resolve my bug.

[osx - How to programmatically delete a file with elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267197/osx-how-to-programmatically-delete-a-file-with-elevated-privileges)

[Obtaining admin privileges to delete files using rm from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588779/obtaining-admin-privileges-to-delete-files-using-rm-from-a-cocoa-app/6269915#6269915)

Answers with Objective-C or Swift are OK.

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif, this is my solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267197/osx-how-to-programmatically-delete-a-file-with-elevated-privileges

Comment: How was the file that you are trying to delete created?  It looks like you are trying to delete your own app?

Comment: Your question is tagged with `iOS` and `Cocoa Touch`, but linked questions are for OS X.