# programmatically force deletion of files

Tags: macos, cocoa

I use `NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace` method `recycleURLs: completionHandler:` to delete files.

If the user does not have the correct permissions e.g. to delete from `/Applications` this produces an error.
`Finder` prompts the user for the `sudo` password then proceeds to delete files.

While it is easy enough to detect the error, and prompt the user, I can't figure out how I could then programmatically force deletion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining admin privileges to delete files using rm from a Cocoa app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588779/obtaining-admin-privileges-to-delete-files-using-rm-from-a-cocoa-app)

Comment: The "answer" is several years old, and refers to method that is deprecated in 10.7